# Reading a flash stream with HTML5

Tags: flash, html, streaming

I know that we can publish a flash rtmfp stream with this piece of code:

```
private const CirrusAddress:String = "rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net";
private const DeveloperKey:String = "your-developer-key";
private var netConnection:NetConnection;

netConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,
netConnectionHandler);
netConnection.connect(CirrusAddress + "/" + DeveloperKey);

private var sendStream:NetStream;

sendStream = new NetStream(netConnection, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,
netStreamHandler);
sendStream.publish("media");
sendStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
sendStream.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
```

So, with this code, a receiver can read the published stream (`sendStream.publish("media")` )  with this code (`recvStream.play("media")`):

```
private var recvStream:NetStream;

recvStream = new NetStream(netConnection, id_of_publishing_client);
recvStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStreamHandler);
recvStream.play("media");
```

But, my question is: Is there an equivalent of the code above in HTML5? In other words, How can I read the published stream with HTML5?

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For being able to use it with HTML5s video support, you have to publish it as a file that's accessible over HTTP and that is, for example, in the webm format.

Comment: How can I publish it as a file on the fly?